# why doesn't texture paint show up on polygon materials?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint details on top of a poliigon material and it doesn't show upon any other mode. How can I fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J3BF.jpg)[image: Texture paint mode]

[image: no decal on top of wooden surfboard poliigon material]

Comment: Please add screenshots so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSByASy15-4)?

Here's a picture (tattoo being the texture you paint on): 
[image]

Comment: This tutorial is awesome. Totally solved my problem. Multilayers are the best! Thanks!

Comment: Can you mark this question as solved_